# Php. Traits. Constants

Tags: php, const, traits

Прошу совета толковых программистов.

Мне часто не хватает возможности (php 5.6) описывать в трейтах константы. Свойства класса есть, а вот константы не ввели.

Собственно 2 вопроса.

**Главный: Как правильно обеспечить множественное наследование с константами на уровне самого php?**

Интересует: Почему разработчики не дали возможность подмешивать в классы константы с помощью трейтов? Может это плохая практика...

Дополнение: (многие не могут понять "А зачем?") Попробую показать.
Есть в БД много таблиц в которых есть поле status: 0 - выкл, 1 - вкл,
делаем трейт (зачем создавать таблицу для двух значений?)

```
trait Status
{
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;

    public static function getStatuses()
    {
        return [
            static::STATUS_INACTIVE => 'Inactive',
            static::STATUS_ACTIVE => 'Active',
        ];
    }

    public function getStatusLabel($nullLabel = '')
    {
        $statuses = static::getStatuses();
        return isset($statuses[$this->status]) ? $statuses[$this->status] : $nullLabel;
    }
}
```

getStatuses() используем для выпадающего списка в форме, getStatusLabel() - тут я думаю и так ясно. 
и это упрощенный пример.

также можно создать другие трейты, а потом уже решать какие трейты подключать для какой-то сущности а какие нет. Одним словом мне нужны именно трейты с константами и я не понимаю почему не дали возможность их использовать в php.

Конечно я могу извратиться и сделать константы через статические свойства

```
trait Status
{
    protected static $STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    public static function STATUS_INACTIVE() { return static::$STATUS_INACTIVE; }

    protected static $STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
    public static function STATUS_ACTIVE() { return static::$STATUS_ACTIVE; }
```

**но хотелось бы понять почему не дали трейтам константы**

Comment: Константы - они на то и константы, что являют собой некую неизменяемую, захардкоженную, сущность имеющую строго ограниченную область применения. Подмешивать константы туда-сюда не айс. Собственно замечали наверное, как в разных классах одного и того-же приложения задаются константы имеющие одни и те-же значения. Смысл в том, чтоб развязать их друг от друга. Глядя на ваш вопрос у меня возникает мысль, что вы пытаетесь использовать константы не для того, для чего они предназначены. Может имеет смысл посмотреть на что-то типа `parse_ini_file`?

Comment: Честно говоря не аргумент для меня. Или я этого не понимаю. Допустим у меня есть базовый класс с константами const ROLE_USER; const ROLE_MANAGER; а также базовый класс с константами const STATUS_ACTIVE; const STATUS_INACTIVE; и соотв методы..
Почему я не могу создать новый класс от двух этих классов? Чем это плохо :/

Comment: Вынесите в отдельный класс константы, и используйте вместо self::CONST_NAME - BaseClass::CONST_NAME, всегда будите знать где менять эти фиксированные значения, а не лазить по классам и искать где от чего там наследовалось, и как изменить что бы все остальные методы не зацепило.

Comment: Ну так недолго дойти и до выноса свойств и методов в общий класс)

Мне ООП подход как раз и нравится тем что мы оперируем сущностями.

Пусть у меня в проекте 40 классов. Сейчас 20 классов используют понятие "Статус". Я создал базовый класс. Ввел константы (см. выше). Написал для них свои методы, геттеры, и т.д. 

В будущем мне понадобится расширять свои классы (те 40).

Я бы мог сделать новый трейт, в котором описать константы (перманентные состояния) и методы для них. И подмешать этот новый трейт в существующие 30 (из 40-ка) классов.

Вот что я хочу. Почему нельзя :/

Comment: Я вообще выпал, если честно. Каким образом константы вообще оказываются привязанными к наследованию, и что вам мешает ссылаться на них обычным путем?

Comment: Расширил свой вопрос примером

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/PHP/comments/46kbrn/why_dont_traits_allow_constants/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Трейты в php реализованы, как copy-paste на уровне интерпретатора. Не стоит ими злоупотреблять.
Решение не позволять константы в трейтах мотивировано сложностью разрешения коллизий имён констант.
Возможно, когда-нибудь эту [проблему](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70986) решат.

А пока, ничто не мешает вам написать так:

```
interface IActiveStatus {
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
}
trait Status
{
    public static function getStatuses()
    {
        return [
            static::STATUS_INACTIVE => 'Inactive',
            static::STATUS_ACTIVE => 'Active',
        ];
    }

    public function getStatusLabel($nullLabel = '')
    {
        $statuses = static::getStatuses();
        return isset($statuses[$this->status]) ? $statuses[$this->status] : $nullLabel;
    }
}

class A implements IActiveStatus {
  use Status;
}
```

или лучше:

```
interface IActiveStatus {
    const STATUS_INACTIVE = 0;
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = 1;
}
trait Status
{
    public static function getStatuses()
    {
        return [
            IActiveStatus::STATUS_INACTIVE => 'Inactive',
            IActiveStatus::STATUS_ACTIVE => 'Active',
        ];
    }

    public function getStatusLabel($nullLabel = '')
    {
        $statuses = static::getStatuses();
        return isset($statuses[$this->status]) ? $statuses[$this->status] : $nullLabel;
    }
}

class A {
  use Status;
}
```

---

Хотя, я бы порекомендовал немножко пересмотреть интерфейс:

```
trait Status{
  protected $status = IActiveStatus::STATUS_INACTIVE;
  public function isActive() {
    return $this->status === IActiveStatus::STATUS_ACTIVE;
  }
  public function isInactive() {
    return $this->status === IActiveStatus::STATUS_INACTIVE;
  }
  public function setActive() {
    $this->status = IActiveStatus::STATUS_ACTIVE;
  }
  public function setInactive() {
    $this->status = IActiveStatus::STATUS_INACTIVE;
  }
  public function getStatusLabel() {
    return ([
        IActiveStatus::STATUS_ACTIVE => 'Active',
        IActiveStatus::STATUS_INACTIVE => 'Inactive',
    ])[$this->status];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно не через трейты а через интерфейсы сделать. Отлично вписывается в множественное наследование

```
interface IStatus {
    const STATUS_ENABLED = 1;
    const STATUS_DISABLED = 0;
}

interface IExtStatus {
    const STATUS_BLOCKED = 2;
}

class Test implements IStatus, IExtStatus {
    const STATUS_LOCAL = 3;
}


echo Test::STATUS_BLOCKED;
echo Test::STATUS_LOCAL;
echo Test::STATUS_ENABLED;
```

Comment: Спасибо за идею но я не зря уперся в трейты. Мне важны и методы, а в интерфейсах нельзя писать тело метода.

Comment: Возможности проверить работоспособность нет. Но там внизу ссылки на патч для php под ваши задачи.

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/traits-with-interfaces